# How to create so file for x64 using android NDK. custom tool chain?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am very new to android and here is what I want to do:

I have some cpp files and want to create so file which will be later used in another android project. Now, I tried with cmake and using linux native libs like libc, libpng, libjepeg etc. But when I used that so file in the other android project, I got linker errors like unsatisfied liker error libc etc.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found
```

Here are the details of files I have:
there is a file color.cpp which used libpng and libjpeg, and color.h
there is another file which uses jasper lib.
and one last file which has all the api's (public head file).
I am combining all this into an so.

I think I have to create so file with android ndk custom toolchain, for it work. I am very new to this android ndk and have no idea how to create so file.

Can you please help?

Also, I have dependencies of libs like libjepeg, libpng, jasper, libc, I am not sure weather those are available in android toolchain or they is any way to add those.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you actually post the errors you get and how you specified the dependencies of your code.

Comment: added error I faced, after creating lib using the linux libs and cmake

Comment: You can't use Linux libraries as they aren't present on Android. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake